# Javascript 'this' as parameter

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, this

I'm trying to copy the value from "FROM" fields into "TO" fields. My first attempt was this:

```
function updateToField(toField,fromField)
{
    toField.value = fromField.value}
}

function verifyFromToFields()
{
var inputs = getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++)
{
    if (inputs[j].name.indexOf('FROM') != -1 && if (inputs[j+1].name.indexOf('TO') != -1)
        {
            var fromField = inputs[j];
            var toField   = inputs[j+1];
            fromField.onchange = function(){updateToField(toField,fromField)};
        }
}
```

The website has several FROM-TO pairs, and this only seem to work for the last pair in the "inputs" array.

Then I tried  this:

```
function updateToField(toField,fromField)
{
    toField.value = fromField.value}
}

function verifyFromToFields()
{
var inputs = getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++)
{
    if (inputs[j].name.indexOf('FROM') != -1 && if (inputs[j+1].name.indexOf('TO') != -1)
        {
            var fromField = inputs[j];
            var toField   = inputs[j+1];
            fromField.onchange = function(){updateToField(toField,this)};
        }
 }
```

With this, when any FROM field in the page is modified, it's copied to the last TO field on the page. I think this is one of those issues I've read about parameters as value or reference, but I can't figure it out. 
Also this is a VERY simplified version of the code, I actually fill the inputs list with a getElementsByClass function and must search through childnodes.
Does anyone have a clue on whats going on?

Comment: Less to do with *this* and pass-by-reference: More to do with *closures*.

Comment: @kojiro -- that's good advice but, by sheer chance, closures (and not this) are exactly what is screwing him up right now!

Comment: @Malvolio that's what I was saying. :)

Comment: @kojiro -- I completely misunderstood what you mean: I thought you were suggesting that he should use closures instead of `this`, which I think is good advice, although here it would have made matters worse rather than better.

Comment: @Malvolio If there were a sane way to attach the *relationship* between fields (`$(fromfield).data("tofield", tofield)`) without using jQuery, using `this` would become dead simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That closure, I do not think it means what you think it means.

This line here:

```
     fromField.onchange = function(){updateToField(toField,this)};
```

means "assign to `onchange` a function that assigns the contents of that fields to whatever `toField` is *at the time of the change!*

Since you only have one variable `toField` all the changeable fields will be assigned to it.

This would work:

```
var setOnChange = function(fromField, toField) {    
   fromField.onchange = function(){updateToField(toField,this)};
};

for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++)
{
    if (inputs[j].name.indexOf('FROM') != -1 && if (inputs[j+1].name.indexOf('TO') != -1)
        {
            setOnChange(inputs[j], inputs[j+1]);
        }
 }
```

**EDIT**: Isaac might have a better explanation of the problem (although I don't really like his solution).

Answer (score 1):

The problem actually has to do with scope. What's happening is that your functions (the ones you assigned to `onchange`) are capturing the variables `toField` and `fromField` and their values keep changing. I know it looks like you've declared them anew each time through the loop, but that's not how JS works; consecutive trips through a loop share a scope, so `fromField` is the same variable each time through and you're merely assigning it a new value in each iteration. So at the end, all of your functions refer to the same `fromField` variable. And that `fromField` variable, naturally, contains the last value you assigned it.

So when you eventually call all of those functions, they all do the same thing, because all of their `fromField`s (and, by the same logic, `toField`s) are the same variable. So that explains why only the last inputs worked; they're what `fromField` and `toField` contained when you ran the functions.

You can fix this by introducing an intermediate function, since functions *do* create new scopes. That way each time through the loop, you get brand new variables.

```
function updateToField(toField,fromField)
{
   toField.value = fromField.value;
}

function verifyFromToFields()
{
  var inputs = getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var j = 0; j < inputs.length; j++)
  {
    function(){
      if (inputs[j].name.indexOf('FROM') != -1 && if (inputs[j+1].name.indexOf('TO') != -1)
      {
          var fromField = inputs[j];
          var toField   = inputs[j+1];
          fromField.onchange = function(){updateToField(toField,fromField)};
      }
   }();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's is because of how closures work. When you assign the `onchange` function you create (for every loop) a new anonymous function that calls `updateToField`, but the value of the `toField` and `this` parameters (or any other you are passing) are not bind to the "current" loop, instead that parameters are bind to the last value of the loop (that's why is only working with your last "TO").

Instead of assigning a new function to `onchange` property try calling the `Function.bind` if you're running in an environment that has that or write one if you don't have it.

[Here are the documentation for `bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

So you can go like this:

```
fromField.onchange = updateToField.bind(this, fromField, toField);
```

Or you can use the other approach that [Malvolio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14480534/20601) wrote.

Comment: what you said about being bound to the current value is true about `toField` but it is not true about `this`. `this` is never lexically scoped, it is always (effectively) local to the function.

Comment: yes, you're totally right but the parameters `fromField` and `toField` are "binded" to the new created function, and he is only using that parameters.

Comment: the past-participle of *bind* is *bound*.  `toField` is the only variable bound; `this` cannot be bound and `fromField` happens not to be bound in this case.

Comment: and what about `updateToField.bind(null, fromField, toField);`? why is not `fromField` bound? PS: sorry for my (bad) english, i'm not an enlish-speaking person.

Comment: In the original version of the code, fromField isn't *used* in the closure; instead `this` is used (which at change-time is equal to what  fromField was at declare-time).  Unused variables are not bound.